# Obtener nombres de un archivo de texto y comparar sus iniciales

Tags: c, comparaciones

Estoy tratando de comparar las iniciales de unos nombres obtenidos previamente de un archivo de texto, el formato del archivo sería este:

```
nombre dato1 dato2
nombre dato1 dato2
nombre dato1 dato2
nombre dato1 dato2
```

Pido al usuario que teclee el nombre del archivo y si es correcto le pido que teclee una letra, que será la inicial a comparar, luego comienzo a leer los datos del archivo y debo saber cuantos nombres empiezan por la letra que indicó el usuario.

El código sería algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *archivo = NULL;
    char fichero[80];
    char nombre[15];
    char inicial[5];
    int i, j, dato1, dato2;

    printf ("Teclea el nombre del archivo: ");
    scanf ("%s", fichero);
    archivo = fopen (fichero, "r");
    if (!archivo) {
        printf ("Error: no se pudo abrir el fichero: %s\n", fichero);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Teclea una inicial: ");
    scanf("%s", &inicial);


    for (i=0; fscanf(archivo, "%s %d %d", nombre, &dato1, &dato2) == 3; i++) {
        printf("%s %d %d\n", nombre, dato1, dato2);
        if (nombre[0]==inicial[0]) {
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("Hay %d nombres que empiezan por la inicial %c \n", j, inicial[0]);
    fclose (archivo);

    return 0;
}
```

Se que en [c](/questions/tagged/c) no se pueden comparar caracteres directamente, pero probé con `strcmp` y tampoco me funcionó. Cual sería la forma correcta de saber cuantos nombres comienzan por la inicial?
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no te funcionó con `strcmp`? ¿Por cierto, este código te compila?

Comment: Claro, porque no iba a compilar? en cuanto al strcmp lo he probado de varias maneras y tira error, solo llega a mostrar el primer nombre del archivo y devuelve un return -1.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas sobre tu programa, inicial es el nombre de un array, por tanto ya es un puntero, lo correcto es

```
scanf("%s", inicial);
```

Segundo, la comparación de caracteres con == va a funcionar bien, realmente vamos a comparar números enteros.
Por último y más importante, lo más probable es que el bucle for no se ejecute, todo va depender de la organización del fichero del que lee, sin ver el fichero es imposible ayudar. Por ejemplo si tenemos un fichero nombres.txt organizado de la siguiente forma:

```
Angel
Roberto
Raul
Miguel
Manuel
Manolo
Mercedes
```

Entonces un bucle como el siguiente debería funcionar:

```
for (i=0; fscanf(archivo, "%s", nombre) == 1; i++)
```

Comment: Ya lo resolví, gracias.